# React : Setting scrollTop on Div doesn't work in a specific case

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

I have been stuck at this since today morning and I still can't figure out where did I go wrong. I wanted to highlight text inside a textarea input type. I know this isn't possible, but I found a clever solution to cheat the viewer into thinking that. [Here](https://codersblock.com/blog/highlight-text-inside-a-textarea/) is the link to the article and [Here](https://codepen.io/lonekorean/pen/gaLEMR) is the link to the codeio pen for the project.

I have been trying to recreate the same using react and normal javascript but the scrollTop property for div with className highlight just doesn't work. If someone could help me debug what I'm doing wrong, that would be wonderful!

```
class CodeTextArea extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {scrollTop: 0, 
                  scrollLeft: 0
                 };
    this.setScroll = this.setScroll.bind(this);
  }
  setScroll(top,left){
    this.setState({scrollTop: top, scrollLeft: left});
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div class="container">
  <div class="backdrop">
    <Highlight scrollTop={this.state.scrollTop} scrollLeft={this.state.scrollLeft}/>
  </div>
  <Textarea setScrollTop={this.setScroll}/>
</div>
    );
  }
}
class Highlight extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.divRef = React.createRef();
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
    if (this.props.scrollTop !== prevProps.scrollTop) {
      /*console.log(this.divRef.current);
      console.log(this.props.scrollTop);
      console.log(this.props.scrollLeft);*/
      this.divRef.current.scrollTop = this.props.scrollTop;
    }

  }
  render(){       
    return (
      <div class="highlights" ref={this.divRef}><mark>This</mark> demo shows how to highlight bits of text within a <mark>textarea</mark>. Alright, that's a lie. You can't actually render markup inside a textarea. However, you can fake it by carefully positioning a div behind the textarea and adding your highlight markup there. JavaScript takes care of syncing the content and scroll position from the textarea to the div, so everything lines up nicely. Hit the toggle button to peek behind the curtain. And feel free to edit this text. All capitalized words will be highlighted.
      </div>
    );
  }
}
class TogglePerspective extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);
    this.buttonRef = React.createRef();
  }
  clickHandler(){

  }
  render(){
    return (
      <button onClick={this.clickHandler} ref={this.buttonRef}>Toggle Perspective</button>
    );
  }
}
class Textarea extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.applyHighlights = this.applyHighlights.bind(this);
    this.textareaRef = React.createRef();
    this.state = {value: 'This demo shows how to highlight bits of text within a textarea. Alright, that\'s a lie. You can\'t actually render markup inside a textarea. However, you can fake it by carefully positioning a div behind the textarea and adding your highlight markup there. JavaScript takes care of syncing the content and scroll position from the textarea to the div, so everything lines up nicely. Hit the toggle button to peek behind the curtain. And feel free to edit this text. All capitalized words will be highlighted.'};
  }

  applyHighlights(text){
    return text
        .replace(/\n$/g, '\n\n')
        .replace(/[A-Z].*?\b/g, '<mark>$&</mark>');
  }

  handleScroll(){
    let scrollTop = this.textareaRef.current.scrollTop;
    let scrollLeft = this.textareaRef.current.scrollLeft;
    this.props.setScrollTop(scrollTop,scrollLeft);
  }

  handleChange(event){
    let textareaValue = event.targrt.value;
    this.setState({value: textareaValue});
    let highlightedText = this.applyHighlights(textareaValue);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <textarea ref={this.textareaRef} value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} onScroll={this.handleScroll}></textarea>
    );
  }
}
class Editor extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
     <div>
    <CodeTextArea />
<TogglePerspective />
</div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
 <Editor />,
 document.getElementById('root')
);
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/gokuafrica/pen/aQmgYo?editors=0110) is the codeIo pen to my recreation. Just please tell me why the 
highlight class div scrollTop attribute is not working.
I don't usually post long code here unless I'm truly frustrated so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `scrollTop` property is being set on `div.highlights` when it should be set on `div.backdrop`.

Move `div.backdrop` into the `Highlight` Component and put the ref on that element:

```
<div class="backdrop" ref={this.divRef}>
<div class="highlights">
    <mark>This</mark> demo shows how to highlight bits of text within a <mark>textarea</mark>.
    Alright, that's a lie. You can't actually render markup inside a textarea. However, you can 
    fake it by carefully positioning a div behind the textarea and adding your highlight markup there. 
    JavaScript takes care of syncing the content and scroll position from the textarea to the div, so everything lines up nicely. 
    Hit the toggle button to peek behind the curtain. And feel free to edit this text. All capitalized words will be highlighted.
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know who you are, but I will find you and I will hug you :)

Man it feels so embarrassing to have such a silly mistake. And was stuck on this for the entire day!!!!!

You solved a big problem for me! Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!